# How can I fix these errors to upload some files into server related with kotlin suspend function?

Tags: kotlin

I had several issues to upload my images to server.
Then I used kotlin suspend function to implement pipeline.
But I met server error following.
[my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd8g9.png)

This is my code.

```
fun Route.customerUploadImage() {
logger.info { "Receiveing Image request" };
post("/me/image") {
    logger.info { "Receiveing Image POST request" };
    call.customerService.saveProfileImage(call.receiveMultipart(), loggedUser().userId!!)
    call.respondStatus(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
}
```

This is the code of customerUploadImage in customerService().

```
suspend fun saveProfileImage(multipart: MultiPartData, userId: Long) {
    logger.info { "Receving Image Request!!!!" }
    multipart.forEachPart { part ->
        (part as? PartData.FileItem)?.run {
            logger.info { this.headers.get("Content-Type") }
            logger.info { "save image, name: $name, file name: $originalFileName" }
            val imageName = allowedProfileImages.firstOrNull { it == name } ?: throw AppException(ErrorCode.INVALID_IMAGE_NAME)
            bao.put(streamProvider(), "profile/$userId-${imageName.toLowerCase()}", blobContentType).also { resourceUrl ->
                logger.info { "resourceUrl - $resourceUrl" }
                dao.get(Customer::class, userId)?.also { customer ->
                    logger.info { "customer - $customer" }
                    dao.put(customer.copy(images = setOf(resourceUrl, *customer.images.toTypedArray())))
                }
            }
        }
        part.dispose()
    }
}
```

I found server could not receive uploaded images file with log info.
So How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found main reason above issue.
Because the "content-type" is setted "application/json" the server is not conduct this data.
So I removed "Content-type"option in header.
It works well.
Original code.

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
```

Now

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
```